# Webscraping a messy webpage with python and beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, css-selectors, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Hi I'm trying to get the name, address and phone number of each of the accounting firms on this page:

http://accountantlist.com.au/x123-Accountants-in-Sydney.aspx?Page=0

I'm having trouble navigating the tree to where the information is.

Using 'beautiful soup' and 'requests' in Python this is how I am attempting to get the company name:

```
import bs4
import requests

page = request.get('http://accountantlist.com.au/x123-Accountants-in-Sydney.aspx?Page=0')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text)

name = soup.select('......')
```

So basically I am just going down the tree following the selectors which I found using the chrome developer tools:

`#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgLawyers > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > a`

Beautiful soup won't accept this path however. I tried it without the '>' symbols as well.

The second method I tried was to just look at the tree and type in the css selectors from body down to where I wanted like this:

`soup.select('body table tbody tr ... etc')`

But this doesn't work either.

I guess in the end this question boils down to how can I write a path that beautiful soup will accept. Could anybody shed some light on how I can solve this problem?

Thanks any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the table with companies by `id` and iterate over each `table` inside:

```
import bs4
import requests

page = requests.get('http://accountantlist.com.au/x123-Accountants-in-Sydney.aspx?Page=0')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content)

for company in soup.select('table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgLawyers tr > td > table'):
    name = company.a.text
    number = company.tr.find_all('td')[-1].text
    address = company.find_all('tr')[-1].td.text

    print {'name': name, 'number': number, 'address': address}
```

Prints:

```
{'address': u'Level 4. 36 Carrington St Sydney. NSW 2000', 'name': u'A D Hill & Co', 'number': u'0292991733'}
{'address': u'Suite 103, Level 1. 84 Pitt Street Sydney. NSW 2000', 'name': u'A2Z Insolvency Solutions', 'number': u'02 8065 6607'}
{'address': u'810 George St Sydney. NSW 2000', 'name': u'AAA iPro Services Australia', 'number': u'1300554959'}
{'address': u'Level 39. 2 Park St Sydney. NSW 2000', 'name': u'AccFin Services', 'number': u'0290047825'}
...
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. In your path how are you able to skip the 'tbody' tag that is under the 'table#ct100...'?

Comment: @Kane yeah, I'm skipping `tbody` - there is no need to always use `>` and follow the direct parent-child relationships.

Comment: @Kane: `table#ct100... tr` Notice the use of the space in place of >. This assumes you only have one level of table nesting though.

Comment: @BoltClock do you mean `table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgLawyers tr` as opposed to `tr > td`? Does that mean that `>` can only be used for one level down?

Comment: @alecxe what does the [1] do in the `number` and `address` parts?

Comment: @Kane there are multiple `td` and `tr` elements inside - this is there to get the appropriate element.